# How to find the number of numeric starts with and find the top 3 count among them?

Tags: visual-c++

I have a list which contains numeric strings. The numeric strings in list may start with any number from 1 to 9 (it doesn't start with "0"). Now i need to find three top occurrences in the list.

Ex:
1234
2345
2343
4356
6434
2343
2222
4545
6666
6653

top three occurrences in the above list respectively are 2,6,4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int occurences[10];  // Store numbers occurences in number index
```

For example if occurence of 5 is equal to 6 then occurences[5] = 6

Second thing you must do is write a function to get count of occurences.

```
int occurence(int number) 
{
     int i=0;
     for(;i<listSize;i++) {
        if(atoi(myList[i]) == number)
             occurences[number]++;
     }
}
```

The last thing you must do is find the biggest 3 element in occurences array.

Comment: Don't you mean `atoi(myList[i][0])` ?

Comment: I'm sorry I supposed it as array. After your comment , I realized it is a list.

Comment: sorry Vicky probably i misunderstood i guess.